# What IIS log parser should I use?

Tags: iis-6, log-files

I've always just gone in and looked at the IIS log files manually. But now I need to sort through several huge log files for an ASP.NET application and I'm thinking some kind of parser would be a good idea, especially if it's got some sort of interface and can access log files remotely.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) is pretty good. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Using-Logparser-Utility-Analyze-ExchangeIIS-Logs.html) on how to use it. The tutorial mentions a GUI tool but gives a dead link. There is a free GUI called [Log Parser Lizard](http://www.lizardl.com/PageHtml.aspx?lng=2&PageId=18&PageListItemId=17) that might be easier than using Log Parser from the command line. Otherwise there are a bunch of commercial products if you google around.

Answer (score 0):

We use a combination of logparser and tail/awk depending on the situation